# Difference between LDFLAGS and ldflags-y

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, kernel-module, kbuild, ldflags

The [kbuild](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt) document says that:

> ldflags-y... [applies] only to the kbuild makefile in which they are assigned....[is used] for all ld invocations happening during a recursive build.

while

> LDFLAGS... [is used] for all invocations of the linker.

I cannot see any difference between them, given a Makefile `m` (and we type `make m`)

- suppose `LDFLAGS := x`, because it applies for all invocations of the linker, then all `ld` invoked in any build session starting from `make m` has value `x` for `LDFLAGS`
- suppose `ldflags-y := y` , becaus if applies for all recursived invocations of `ld`, then all `ld` invoked (by any build session starting from `make m`) has also value `y` for `LDFLAGS`

Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: The documentation you quoted already explains a difference between these two, so no, they do not define the same thing.  But that seems too obvious, so perhaps you can rephrase the question to clarify what it is that you really want to know?

Comment: @JohnBollinger thank you, I've rephrased the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > [applies] only to the kbuild makefile in which they are assigned

means that the link flags defined by that variable in a given makefile are used only in rules appearing in the same makefile.  They are not inherited from a parent makefile, and they are not transmitted to sub-`make`s controlled by other makefiles.

> > [is used] for all ld invocations happening during a recursive build.

This is a statement about the facility in general, not about specific flags designated via any particular use of that facility.  It says that you can use an `ldflags-y` variable in any kbuild makefile, and expect to see the behavior described in the docs -- linker invocations in rules appearing directly in the same makefile will use those flags, but they will not automatically be conveyed to sub-`make`s in other directories.

On the other hand, this ...

> > LDFLAGS... [is used] for all invocations of the linker.

... appears in the documentation for architecture makefiles.  The point of these, as described in the docs, is to define flags appropriate for the overall build and (substantially) everything in it.  This variable should be defined *only* in such a makefile, and the quotation says that the linker flags defined that way are used in all linker runs during the build, no matter in what makefile the corresponding rule appears (including, notably, in directories that are not in the same tree as the architecture makefile).

The docs go on to say that `ldflags-y` can be used for further customization, which you should take to indicate that *both* are applied in linker runs.  Reading a bit more closely between the lines, you should expect the (global) `LDFLAGS` to appear earlier in the linker command than the (local) `ldflags-y`.

> I cannot see any difference between them, given a Makefile m (and we
>   type make m)
>
> - suppose LDFLAGS := x, because it applies for all invocations of the linker, then all ld invoked in any build session starting from
>     make m has value x for LDFLAGS

Yes and no.  A general kbuild makefile `m` *shouldn't* provide a definition for `LDFLAGS`.  That belongs only in the appropriate architecture makefile.  It's unclear what would happen if a kbuild makefile did so anyway, but I suspect that it would cascade to sub-`make`s.

Additionally, you *shouldn't* attempt to `make` a subtree directly if it is configured for kbuild.  The system is not designed for that.

> - suppose ldflags-y := y , becaus if applies for all recursived invocations of ld, then all ld invoked (by any build session starting
>     from make m) has also value y for LDFLAGS

No.  The ability to use an `ldflags-y` variable to provide local link-flag customizations applies to all kbuild makefiles.  The specific flags provided that way by a particular makefile do not cascade to sub-`make`s.

Comment: Thank you.  It's a great answer which clarifies every corners of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The [help](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/cb8vu1/difference_between_ldflags_and_ldflagsy/ethbq16?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) from a reddit user clarifies the difference: actually `ldflags-y` applies <s>for `ld` invocations happen in descending builds, but not</s> for the builds of the current Makefile. In short, `LDFLAGS` defines the top<s>, then descending builds may custom this value using `ldflags-y`</s>.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you've got it or not.  What you've said doesn't sound quite right to me.

Comment: Sorry, I've misunderstood the document.